# Raphael, animation of points

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a function which displays lines (x and y coordinates) based on the time information. The x and y coordinates specify the position of the drawn points whereas time represents the timestamps (in milliseconds) of the respective points.

Currently, there is a function which displays line as below

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/master/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function drawLine(points) {
            var paths = ['M ' + points[0].x + ' ' + points[0].y];
            for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
                var p = points[i];
                paths.push(paths[i - 1] + ' L ' + p.x + ' ' + p.y);
            }
            var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 500, 500);  
            var line = paper.path(paths[0]);
            var next = 1;

            function animate() {
                if (paths[next]) {  
                    duration = points[next].t - points[next - 1].t        
                    line.animate({ path: paths[next] }, duration, 'linear', animate);
                    next++;
                }
            }
            animate();
        }
    </script>
```

And the function can be called using associative arrays as follows:

```
    drawLine([
                { x: 0, y: 0, t: 0 },
                { x: 100, y: 230, t: 1520 },
                { x: 210, y: 290, t: 3850 },
                { x: 150, y: 200, t: 5060 },
            ]);
```

The question is, how can I modify this function to display points and not the lines?

Comment: you want draw points to coordinates from the Array ? What is `t` parameter here ? suggestion - draw circle of little radius

Comment: yes… @eicto is right, just draw circles, or use an <use> tag to use any kind of visualization for the points, using a single path here is tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a drawPoint method, which will take an object with `x` and `y` properties

```
function drawPoint(point) {
    paper.circle(point.x, point.y, 5).attr('fill', 'red');
};
```

Then call it from your `animate` function, before the `points[next]` comparison

```
drawPoint(points[next - 1]);
```

Here's the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/2krgN/

If you don't want the lines, then you don't need paths

```
function drawPoints(points){
    var paper = new Raphael('canvas_container', 500, 500),
        idx  = 0;

    function animate(){
        if(points[idx]){
            var currP = points[idx],
                prevP = points[idx - 1],
                d     = currP.t - (prevP ? prevP.t : 0 );
            paper.circle(currP.x, currP.y, 1)
                 .attr('fill', 'red')
                 .animate({r:5}, d, animate);
            idx++       
        }
    }
    animate();
}
```

The recursive `animate` callback might be a little difficult to understand/read, so might just want to use a `setTimeout`. Also you can pass a string with the `id` of an element to the `Raphael` constructor and the library will find the DOM node for you.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/Q5G5y/2/